# How to compile 32-bit programs in linux 64-bit environment

Tags: linux

When I made lab1 of mit6.828, I tried to make the official lab file, and an error occurred

> +ld obj/kern/kernel
> ld: warning: section '.bss' type changed to PROGBITS
> ld: obj/kern/printfmt.o: in function 'printnum':
> lib/printfmt.c:41: undefined reference to '__udivdi3'
> ld: lib/printfmt.c:49: undefined reference to '__umoddi3'
> make: *** [kern/Makefrag:71: obj/kern/kernel]

My qemu is already installed and can be used, I guess it should be a compilation problem. The official said that this is because of the lack of a 32-bit compiler, and the gcc-mutilib package needs to be installed
But I still can't compile normally after installation, and the same error is reported

My multi-architecture is enabled, and the compilation tools are also installed

**gcc-mutilib & g++-mutilib** are installed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compile-32-bit-program-64-bit-gcc-c-c/

Otherwise, a bit more detail is needed - maybe a link to the actual source you're compiling and what command(s) you're running